# How to custom join tables to populate nested one-to-many DTO with Micronaut?

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-data

I am trying to join a few tables not using the primary keys and with a custom WHERE and have Micronaut consume the response correctly into DTOs.

Given contact table, with a one-to-many relationship with contact_account table, not through PK, I'd like to do an outer-join of contact_account and fill a list nested in the main Contact DTO.

```
@Introspected
@Table(schema = "my_schema")
@MappedEntity("contact_account")
public class ContactAccount {
  ...
}

@Introspected
@Table(schema = "my_schema")
@MappedEntity("contact")
public class Contact {
   ...
   private List<ContactAccount> contactAccount;
}

@JdbcRepository(dialect = Dialect.POSTGRES)
public abstract class ContactTable implements PageableRepository<Contact, Long> {
 ...
  @Query("Select ...")  // <== Perhaps use a custom query, or alternatively,
                        // use other annotations to express a non-PK one-to-many relationship
   public abstract List<Contact> findBlah(...);
}
```

1. If using @Query (preferred): What query should I use, or what annotations should be specified to express this outer-join relationship in a way that Micronaut will consume it correctly?
2. If using other annotations: how to (i) specify one-to-many outer left join on multiple columns? (ii) specify additional WHERE conditions?
3. How to get Micronaut to correctly fill the `contactAccount' list inside Contact?

I managed to do something similar with a one-to-one relationship, which was quite clunky, as I had to specify every single column of one table in the query and assign it to an alias.
I used `@Join(value = "<DTO field name>", alias = "cpa_")`
It would have been nice if I could have used '*' and not be forced to specify all columns.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to specify the relation using `@Relation` annotation.
2. You don't need to use a custom query, it should be enough just to add `@Join`, for multiple columns, `@JoinColumns` can be used.
3. You need to have relations defined, for a custom query, you would need to have proper column naming and prefixes for the relations.

Comment: Unfortunately, Micronaut does not seem to support @JoinColumns correctly.
https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-data/issues/2385

Comment: 1. With `@Relation` you need to specify a `mappedBy`, where it is not clear how to specify multi columns (fields).
2. `@Relation` and `@JoinColumns` seem to be doing the same thing, so it's not clear how to use both, if a tall